# Is there anyway to use a third-party library that has been created for .NET Framework, in .NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core-2.0

The multi-targeting platform lets us have one codebase and produce different binaries for different platforms. You can created outputs (DLL files) for .NET Framework and .NET Core both at the same time. And AMAIK this is possible because of .NET Standard that works as the pillar in this scenario. That's what I find on Google.

But my question is not my own libraries. I have a bunch of DLL files that are already there, built for .NET Framework and are somehow essential to our development.

Some third party libraries that are beyond our control prevent us from migrating to .NET Core. Is there anyway that we can use them in .NET Core?

Comment: With .net core 2.0 they allowed installing full .net framework packages into .net core 2.0 apps, with the understanding that stuff may break at runtime.

Comment: You can try to create .net standard library, add .net framework lib as reference. And add your .net standard lib to you .net core project. And be careful with runtime breaks as @zaitsman said.